# Get array from PHP to JS using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

When I click add new button in data table, i want to create drop down instead of text boxes.this drop down values will have to retrieve the data from database.My code is below.

```
//button to add new row
function addeditRow(oTable, nRow) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "menudrop.php",
        success: function(html) {
            $("#one").append(html);
        }
    });  
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
    var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);
    jqTds[0].innerHTML = '';
    jqTds[1].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small"  id="two" value="' + aData[1] + '">';
    jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<SELECT id="one"  name="menus"><OPTION></OPTION></SELECT>';
    jqTds[3].innerHTML = '<a class="edit" href="">Save</a>';
    jqTds[4].innerHTML = '<a class="cancel" href="">Cancel</a>';
}
```

menudrop.php

```
<?php
    require_once("database/connect.php");

    $db = new Database;
    $db->mquery('a_menus','*');
    $menus = $db->fetchdata();
    $items = array();
    foreach($menus as $ms) {
        $items[] = $ms->menu_name;
    }
    print_r($items);
?>
```

This is not works. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Select should have id="one" not the option and return <option>value</option> from PHP page

Comment: See your PHP code where you have return options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the php function `json_encode($items);` to return a json from the php instead of printing the values

```
<?php
    require_once("database/connect.php");

    $db = new Database;
    $db->mquery('a_menus','*');
    $menus = $db->fetchdata();
    $items = array();
    foreach($menus as $ms) {
        $items[] = $ms->menu_name;
    }
   echo json_encode($items);
?>
```

in ajax to create a select we use in the success function something similar to this:

```
success: function(html) {
           $("#one").append('<select name="menus">');
           $.foreach(html,function(index,val){
                $("#one").append('<option value="'+val.id+'">'+val.name+'</option>');//assuming that in your resulting query exist a field named id and a field named name
            });
            $("#one").append('</select>');
        }
```